# Как составить условие c помощью jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как составить такое условие jQuery: 
**выбрать все чекбоксы на странице со значением (3, 8, 19), которые находятся в переменной item, и спрятать родителя, в котором эти чекбоксы находятся?**

```
<ul>
<li class="letter"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxEmail" value="."$row[0]".'></li>
<li class="letter"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxEmail" value="."$row[0]".'></li>
<li class="letter"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxEmail" value="."$row[0]".'></li>
.....
</ul>
```

Как найти родителя и спрятать, я разобрался:

```
$(".checkboxEmail").parent("letter").hide();
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, но найти, думаю, можно так:

    $('form').find('.checkboxEmail[value="3"]').parent('li').parent('ul').hide();

Comment: var item = [ 1,2,3 ];
    jQuery.each(item, function() { 
    ..... 
    $("ul").find(".checkboxEmail[value='']").parent("li").hide();
    });

Не пойму, как значение добавить чекбоксам в массиве.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
item.forEach(function(number, index) {
    $('ul').find('.checkboxEmail[value="' + number +'"]').parent('li').parent('ul').hide();
});
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

Вначале все выбираем, потом потом прячем родителя.

```
$('.checkboxEmail[value="3"]').attr('selected','selected');
$('.checkboxEmail[value="8"]').attr('selected','selected');
$('.checkboxEmail[value="19"]').attr('selected','selected');
$('.checkboxEmail[value="3"]').parent('li').parent('ul:first').hide();
```